update sql database based on edited content of ckeditor in codeigniter3
Im new to codeigniter3 and blade. and i have some trubble to update my sql database when the ckeditor content updated.
here i have a view page which send report_id as hidden variable to controller.
then in controller i fetch related column values of sql database in phpmyadmin to ckeditor content.
thats ok and in page load the sql table content displayed on ckeditor content.
now, when i updated the ckeditor, i nead to sql database table be updated.
but i cant do that.
could you please provide any guid to solve that?
below is my code parts:
//--start view file: PROFIL_YONETIMI_BOS_DUZENLE.blade.php

{!! form_open('#',array('class'=>'text-left mt-2','id'=>'BOS_FORM','onsubmit'=>"ajax(this,'".$user_base_url."/profil/profil_yonetimi_BOS_duzenle');return false;")) !!}
    <input hidden type="hidden" name="AJAX_ISLEM" value="BOS_DUZENLE">
    <input hidden type="hidden" name="REPORT_ID" value="{{$AKTIF_PROFIL->id}}">
    <div class="panel panel-primary tabs-style-1">
        <div class="panel-body tabs-menu-body main-content-body-right bg-white border">
            <div class="tab-content">
                    {!! FORM_Create($BOS,$AKTIF_PROFIL) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-3 offset-lg-9 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-with-icon float-right btn-block"><i class="typcn typcn-news"></i>{{ceviri('rapor_yonetimi_duzenle')}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! form_close() !!}
//--end view file: PROFIL_YONETIMI_BOS_DUZENLE.blade.php

// start controller
public function profil_yonetimi_BOS_duzenle(){
        $this->user_oturum_yetki_kontrol();
        $REPORT_ID = $this->input->post('REPORT_ID');
        $REPORT_DB=$this->user_model->GENEL_ICERIK($REPORT_ID, $ISSUE='profil_yonetimi_BOS');
        $FORM_KURALLARI = $this->FORM_KURALLARI_RAPOR('BOS',$REPORT_DB);  
        $this->ICERIK_VERISI['REPORT_DB']=$REPORT_DB;
        $this->ICERIK_VERISI['BOS'] = $FORM_KURALLARI;
        $this->ICERIK_VERISI['sayfa'] = "profil_yonetimi_BOS_duzenle";
        $this->ICERIK_VERISI['kapsam'] = "user.PROFIL.kapsam.profil_yonetimi";
        $this->blade->display('user/PROFIL/PROFIL_YONETIMI_BOS_DUZENLE', $this->ICERIK_VERISI); // Load the new view

        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            $AJAX_ISLEM=$this->input->post('AJAX_ISLEM');

            if($AJAX_ISLEM=="BOS_DUZENLE"){
                $FORM_KURALLARI = $this->FORM_KURALLARI_RAPOR('BOS',$REPORT_DB);                  
                $FORM_VERISI['profil_yonetimi_BOS']=$FORM_KURALLARI['BOS'];
                $BOS_DUZENLEME_SORGUSU=$this->user_model->BOS_DUZENLE($REPORT_ID,$FORM_VERISI);                
            }
        }else{
            $this->ICERIK_VERISI['sayfa']="profil_yonetimi_BOS_duzenle";
            $this->ICERIK_VERISI['kapsam']="user.PROFIL.kapsam.profil_yonetimi";
            $this->ICERIK_VERISI['BOS']=$this->user_model->GENEL_ICERIK($REPORT_ID, $ISSUE='profil_yonetimi_BOS');
            $this->blade->display('user/PROFIL/PROFIL_YONETIMI_BOS_DUZENLE',$this->ICERIK_VERISI);
        }    
    } 

//end controller
// start model

public function BOS_DUZENLE($ID, $FORM_VERISI) {
        $this->db->select('profil_yonetimi_BOS');
        $this->db->from('kullanici_profilleri');
        $this->db->where('id', $ID);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row()->profil_yonetimi_BOS;
          } else {
                 return null;
             }
          }
            public function GENEL_ICERIK($ID, $ISSUE) {
                // Make sure to escape the column name to prevent SQL injection
                if (!in_array($ISSUE, ['profil_yonetimi_BOS', ...])) {
                    return null; // Return null if the column name is not allowed
                }
            
                $this->db->select($ISSUE);
                $this->db->from('kullanici_profilleri');
                $this->db->where('id', $ID);
                $query = $this->db->get();
            
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $row = $query->row();
                    return $row->$ISSUE;
                } else {
                    return null; // Return null if no record is found
                }
            } 
//end model


Please also show your view and model.

i edit post and include fully the codes
